# Facebook invite friends box got cut off

Tags: facebook

I have an invite friends box on my app which is an iframe tab. When click to invite friend almost half of it got cut off on the right where the ads are showing. I have seen some apps have this pop up box goes over the ads column. How do that do that? (Sample http://www.facebook.com/pages/Inclusive-India/108027602808?v=app_4949752878&ref=ts)

My app code is (not complete since i dont know how to properly put the code here -_-")

```
    <fb:request-form
        action=\"action url\"
        method=\"POST\"
        invite=\"true\"
        type=\"Like Us\"
        content="Text text text
            <fb:req-choice url='blah blah blah'
            label='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Try it!",ENT_QUOTES); ?>'
            /> 
        " > 

        <fb:multi-friend-selector
            showborder="false"
            actiontext="Share text"
            exclude_ids=""
            rows="3"
            cols="3"
            condensed="false"
        /> 
    </fb:request-form> 
</fb:fbml>

<script>
  FB.init({appId: '<?php print FACEBOOK_APP_ID; ?>', 
    status: true,
    cookie: true, xfbml: true
    });

  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

</script>
```

Comment: same problem, no solution....